# File is in docker, but getting No such file or directory error

Tags: docker

I have a php image. While build happens, `Dockerfile` copies a file from my machine into the container. This is a bash script, only an echo in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting php-fpm7.4"
```

Here is the relevant part of my `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY ./scripts/postinstall.sh /var/www/html/postinstall.sh
RUN chmod 775 /var/www/html/postinstall.sh
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

If I just run a new instance of this image and start my script it works fine:

```
vaso@vaso:/srv/www/mito/docker$ docker run -it docker_php
root@563cf480a9c7:/var/www/html# /var/www/html/postinstall.sh
Starting php-fpm7.4
```

Even, the `ls -la` is show the file:

```
root@2ea46a681abc:/var/www/html# ls -la /var/www/html/postinstall.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 168 Nov  4 16:44 /var/www/html/postinstall.sh
```

When I try to run `docker-compose up` I am getting this:

```
vaso@vaso:/srv/www/mito/docker$ docker-compose up
Starting phpfpm ...
Starting phpfpm ... done
....
Attaching to mysql, phpfpm, webserver
phpfpm   | /bin/bash: /var/www/html/postinstall.sh: No such file or directory
phpfpm exited with code 127
```

I want to do some things in this sh file, to setup my project, but since this error, I can not:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting php-fpm7.4"
#/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 -F -R &
#echo "Composer install vendor directory"
#composer install
#echo "Databse migration"
#php yii migrate
```

Can somebody tell me what do I miss?

**EDIT**

Here is my complete `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build: php
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    container_name: phpfpm
    expose:
      - '9003'
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ../app:/var/www/html
      - ./dockerlive/logs:/var/log
      - php-fpm-socket:/var/run/php
    #command: "/bin/bash -c '/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 -F -R'"
    command: /bin/bash -c '/var/www/html/postinstall.sh'
    #entrypoint: /var/www/html/postinstall.sh
    links:
      - db
  nginx:
    build: nginx
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    depends_on:
      - php
      - db
    volumes:
      - ../app:/var/www/html
      - ./dockerlive/logs:/var/log/nginx
      - php-fpm-socket:/var/run/php
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=localhost
      - NGINX_PORT=80
    command: /bin/bash -c "chgrp www-data -R /var/www/html && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
  db:
    build: database
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mito
volumes:
  php-fpm-socket:
```

Comment: What does the docker-compose file look like?

Comment: @Paolo I've added to the post.

Comment: @Paolo Oh! Is it possible that the nginx is depend on php, and when nginx mounting the volume, that is override the php?

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up --force-recreate` ?  Use `docker ps` to get the image that `docker-compose` is running and try to run it manually, see if the file is there.

Comment: My bad I was under the impression that you still use the Dockerfile in order to build your image in docker-compose, that's why I mentioned the build context. Hmm maybe the volumes path aren't ok.

Comment: @dejanualex you do! Build context could be wrong, I am just assuming that those are subdirectories containing Dockerfiles.